# BootReceiver not working in all android devices

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

i have been trying to overcome issue of Boot_complete receiver not working in certain devices.

Like Vivo device which have iManager app with auto-start manager.
Where user can toggle app from auto start on device boot.

What should i use along with below as intent-filter to restart my service after device reboot.

Earlier thought of using Battery_Change receiver but it won't work from manifest, as i has to be runtime receiver register.

Any suggestion would be really help-full.

Below is what i have used as intent-filter for my app. In most devices its working as expected. But not in all.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: have you set the permissions correctly in manifest?

Comment: Where is your app installed, external or internal storage?

Comment: Yes @chalithageekiyanage I have kept permission of receving boot_complete in manifest as well.

Comment: What is the installed location?

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing my team and I discovered when facing a similar issue.
You can monitor the usb state like so:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And if memory serves me right, this will send a broadcast **before** the regular `BOOT_COMPLETED` action telling you there is or isn't anything USB connected.

Some manufacturers use their own version of `BOOT_COMPLETED` as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42622385/716810) but the `USB_STATE` is an alternative, based on the things you want to do. Do note you **can** get multiple broadcasts using this method!

Alternatively you could look into using an `AccessibilityService` or the `JobService` from the firebase sdk. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524459/broadcast-receiver-not-working-after-device-reboot-in-android?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you for suggesting USB_State giving it a try.
Well basically below is what i can see in logcat that iManager is blocking up app from getting boot_complete action.


05-01 07:39:51.110 2155-2183/? W/BroadcastQueue: Cancel launching app com.testing.app/10178 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }: process is forbid to start up

Comment: Hi, @Jordy I have tried USB_STATE but upon reboot unable to intercept same event in receiver.

Comment: Hi @Jordy Getting below issue

05-01 16:35:03.394 2219-4544/? W/BroadcastQueue: Cancel launching app com.testing.app/10180 for broadcast Intent { act=android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }: process is forbid to start up

Comment: Hi @jordylangen Getting below issue

`05-01 16:35:03.394 2219-4544/? W/BroadcastQueue: Cancel launching app com.testing.app/10180 for broadcast Intent { act=android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }: process is forbid to start up`

Comment: Does iManager block every kind of intent receiving? You could try this by checking if the user unlocks the screen (`android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT`)

Comment: Updated my answer, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524459/broadcast-receiver-not-working-after-device-reboot-in-android?rq=1