# Receiving data sms in android oreo and above

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have used implicit broadcast receiver to receive data sms but now with android O it's not possible anymore

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.SMSReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="sms"/>
            <data android:port="10013"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Any ideas on how to implement data sms on android O and above?

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789572/oreo-broadcastreceiver-sms-received-not-working

Answer (score -1):

declare BROADCAST RECEIVER in manifest file

```
  <receiver android:name=".SMSReader">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" android:exported="true">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Broadcast reciever class

```
public class SMSReader extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private Intent smsIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            try {
                if (bundle != null) {
                    final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                        SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                        String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                        long time = currentMessage.getTimestampMillis();
                        String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                        if (senderNum.contains("UPI")) ;
                        {
                            String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                            if (message.contains("debit")) {
                                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                                smsIntent = new Intent("read");
                                smsIntent.putExtra("message", message);
                                smsIntent.putExtra("sender", senderNum);

                                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(smsIntent);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SMSReader", "Exception" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in onCreate()

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("read"));
```

create a separate method to handle SMS

```
 private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("read")) {
                final String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                final String sender = intent.getStringExtra("sender");
                formatMessage(message,sender);
            }
        }
    };
```