# Unable to read sms Using Broad cast receiver from OREO

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, one-time-password, android-doze

Reading Otp from SmsManager and update the text feild Automatically.

I followed below article

Automatically-read-OTP from SMSes — Android 4.3 to 8.x by STYLABS https://link.medium.com/sk22tU4qTR

I'm facing issue while implementing..
It works below Oreo versions 8.0 .

From Oreo version Broadcast receiver is not triggering.

Because of Doze Mode broadcast receivers are not triggering.But it's working till nougat version.

Alternative is SMS Retraival API from Google .But I don't want to go with that currently .

How to do this ? It is not triggering Once the sms is received to phone .

Comment: On What device are you running this ?

Comment: Moto g5 s plus.And it is not working in all Oreo version devices , I tested.

Comment: Well I think the problem is due to autostart and battery optimization features which various devices come with from android Oreo , you can refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789572/oreo-broadcastreceiver-sms-received-not-working/52016035#52016035) or any other answer on this question .

Comment: Okay let me check and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Yes After OREO update You can not read SMS by READ_SMS permission.

Don't worry,

You can replace :

```
READ_SMS permission with RECEIVE_SMS
```

Now Oreo as well as other version also be able to read the SMS.