# No resources found that matches at AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-manifest, accessibilityservice

I am trying to follow this solution [Broadcast Receiver Not Working After Device Reboot in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524459/broadcast-receiver-not-working-after-device-reboot-in-android), but I get the following error:

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/my_accessibility_service').

[image]

With my_accessibility_service.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<accessibility-service
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:packageNames="myapp"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:description="@string/service_desc"
    android:notificationTimeout="100">
</accessibility-service>
```

Why is it happening?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the compile error by transferring the file at layout folder and instead or @xml wrote @layout.