# restart the phone after phone call

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I can't catch phone calls after the phone restart. My receiver code is as follows. how can I catch calls when the phone restarts.

```
<receiver 
   android:name="InterceptCall"
   android:exported="true"
   android:enabled="true">
  <intent-filter android:priority="999">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Does that answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524459/broadcast-receiver-not-working-after-device-reboot-in-android

Comment: Actually this should work. Which android version are you targeting? did you make sure that one of the following permissions is granted? READ_PHONE_STATE/READ_CALL_LOG